# CSS formatting to create a button in D3 JS

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I would like to create a button as shown below [image]

Given below is what I have :

```
var button = svg.append("foreignObject")
.attr("x", "5")
.attr("y", "380")
.attr("width", 300)
.attr("height", 40)
.attr("border-radius", "1")
.style("border", "1px solid blue")
.append("xhtml:body")
.html('View');
```

But this is not close to the expected output. Can I get some assistance in getting the CSS in place for this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to attach styles directly to the HTML. Something along the following lines should work:

```
let button = svg
  .append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", "5")
  .attr("y", "380")
  .attr("width", 320)
  .attr("height", 44)
  .append("xhtml:body")
  .style("width", "300px")
  .style("height", "40px")
  .style("border-radius", "5px")
  .style("border", "2px solid blue")
  .html("View");
```